# Sound conflict between pulseaudio and gnome causing sound to come out of wrong speakers

Tags: gnome, sound, pulseaudio

I recently updated to Ubuntu 20.04 and, for reasons I can't remember, I also have pavucontrol (the pulseaudio sound controller) installed. Now I have all sorts of problems with sound coming out of the wrong place with certain applications when I have both the internal speaker and an external headset plugged in. For example, for a recent Skype call, the ringing sound came through the headset, but the person's voice came through the (barely audible) computer speaker.

The only way to fix this is to adjust sound volume and source in pavucontrol; gnome sound settings doesn't seem to have enough controls to do it. I tried uninstalling pavucontrol to get gnome back in control, but this just made it impossible to get audio coming out of the right place.

Is there a way to fix this and get back to gnome controlling all aspects of sound?